# Modify the return/print option of a custom function in r

Tags: r, function, return-value, func

I built a custom function in which it prints an output of the class and it's probability (classifier), like the following:

```
fun(formula, data)
> "Class" 0.5
```

I integrate this `fun` into another function `new_fun`, but I use a modified result of `fun` as an output for `new_fun`. Therefore, I don't need to original output of `fun` of the class and probability. Is there a way to avoid returning/printing the original output once it's integrated  into `new_fun`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `capture.output`:

```
f <- function() {print("test"); "result"}
g <- function() { capture.output(result<-f()); result}


f()
#> [1] "test"
#> [1] "result"
g()
#> [1] "result"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In the example you provided, this would be:

```
new_fun <- function(...){
  myformula <- ...
  mydata <- ...

  #Call to fun with captured output
  capture.output( funresult <- fun(myformula, mydata))

  #Process further funresult
  ...
  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this in my code. Where should I include { capture.output(result<-f()); result} ? At the end of my second function?